# Unable to update data in views in fragment

Tags: java, android, android-fragments, android-viewpager

I have a view pager that returns same fragment with different data from adapter every time i swap but despite of the fact that different data is received it displaying the same data over and over again, how can i make fragment update its data

the structure is, there is a fragment that has a listview and when i click on the listview item it replaces a fragment that has viewpager and setting its adapter, the adapter is FragmentPagerAdapter and returns a fragment with argument now fragment uses its argument and display data, every time getview called of adapter returning the same fragment with different data

here is the code:

when list item clicked:

```
replaceFragment(ReportPaginationFragment.newInstance(i, isFromList), true, true);
```

ReportPaginationFragment:

```
 viewPager.setAdapter(new ReportPaginationAdapter(getFragmentManager(), reportID, appointmentObjectArrayList, isFromList, listPosition ));
```

Adapter:

```
 reportId = appointmentObjectArrayList.get(item++).getId();
    return NewDrReportFragment.newInstance(reportId);
```

appointmentObjectArrayList is arraylist that has data

Thanks in advance

Comment: can you post your code

Comment: Usually, the `FragmentManager` will not completely destroy the fragment, it would just destroy its `view`. So make sure you assign new data inside the `onCreateView()` method of the fragment. You can alse add a `Log.d()` statement inside the method where you assign data to adapter and see if that method gets called everytime you swipe in.

Comment: edited question

Answer (score 3):

Instead of `addFragment`, `replace` is better choice.

```
FragmentManager fragmentManager = getSupportFragmentManager();
FragmentTransaction fragmentTransaction = fragmentManager.beginTransaction();
fragmentTransaction.replace(R.id.container_body, fragment);
fragmentTransaction.commit();
```

Comment: where im adding fragment? its all replacement

Comment: @blackHawk Try calling commit() as well.

Answer (score 0):

```
for (int i=0;i<categoryList.size();i++){
            Category category=categoryList.get(i);
            FoodFragment foodFragment = new FoodFragment();
            foodFragment.setCategory(category);
            pagerAdapter.addFragment(foodFragment, category.getName());
        }
```

lets take this example. Maybe you are not setting differrent data onto pageAdapter properly.
can you share your code for more information?